# iOS library not loaded when using IPA

Tags: ios, xcode, dlsym

My code uses an external library using `dlsym` (for reasons out of my control).

In order Xcode to find my library, I had to do 2 things:

- `-force_load "$(SRCROOT)/pathTo/myLibrary.a"`
- Dead-Code Stripping: NO

This works fine when running wit the debug profile. Both on the simulator and on a physical device, the library is loaded and works.

However if I create an AdHoc IPA file and install it on my device, this same library is no longer found.

What could be the difference?

Comment: Are you sure that an ipa has 'myLibrary.a' file inside? App Store won't allow to do that. Just try to link a library to project through Build Phases -> Link libraries and try to add '-ObjC' flag to Other Linked Flags, maybe it will work for you. Delete your library from Copy Bundle Resources if it's there.

Comment: Yes if I open the IPA with an archive browser I see the .a file. But why wouldn't I want this? How else can the device receive this library??

Comment: You can add only one executable file to an .app, name of which is a value for key 'CFBundleExecutable' from Info.plist. Your library will be compiled into when you run 'build' command at Xcode.

Comment: I see what you are saying. So the library.a that I see in my package was indeed because it was in "copy bundle", I removed it. Still the same issue however. Now I'm not sure how to check if the library was really included in the compiled file...

Comment: You can decompile it 'otool -tV -arch arm64 ../my.app/executable_file | grep ClassName', where 'ClassName' is a name of any class from your library. If it there you will see it.

Comment: What is supposed to be the output of this? I get nothing, no matter what class name I write, even `AppDelegate`.

Comment: I think I'm onto something. "Strip Linked Product"

Comment: If output gives nothing it means that the executable file was not linked with your library, it's odd, it should have been.

Comment: Please try just ''otool -tV ../my.app/executable_file | grep AppDelegate'', maybe the executable doesn't have arm64 architecture.

Comment: Yep, better now. It found my library, but it's probably because I solved the issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the issue:

In **Build Settings → Deployment → Strip Linked Product**, select
`NO`.